# Need help understanding error "manifest is not in the package root" while registering Windows 10 package

Tags: windows, server, package, microsoft-edge

I am trying to register the Windows 10 Edge package with Windows Server 2016.  I have successfully installed the store thanks to a forum I found and it opens but remains untested.  I am trying to do the same with Edge.  I've copied the app package from the installer iso to C:\Windows\systemapps and ran the power shell script:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\windows\systemapps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

And get the following error:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, Install failed. Please contact your software vendor.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
Rejecting a request to register from Appxmanifest.xml because the manifest is not in the package root.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] a80e1223-2787-0000-dc3e-12a98727d301 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID a80e1223-2787-0000-dc3e-12a98727d301
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\windows\systemapps\Microsoft.MicrosoftE ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\windows\syst...ppxmanifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I've verified the manifest is in the package root so other than that I can't figure out what it means.  Can someone help me understand what it's looking for?

Reference for store install: http://virtualcustoms.net/showthread.php/72904-Install-Microsoft-Store-and-Apps-on-Windows-10-LTSB-2016

Comment: any sign of answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to do the same thing and I have found if I copy the app to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps then it installs without complaining about not being in the root and then the Edge icon also appears on the start menu.

The command to run is:

```
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
```

Whilst this allows the app to install and I am able to launch it from the start menu it closes after about 2 seconds and looking in the log (Application and Service Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Apps\Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational it shows this error so it looks like there is still something else that needs to be done to get this working:

```
ActivateApplicationForContractByAppIdAsUserWithHost of the app Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge for the Windows.Launch contract failed with The app didn't start..
```

Robin

Comment: Any sign of answer?

Comment: No sorry never did resolve this and couldn't really find much support for this. We are not really using Windows Store apps as find them too unreliable - issues that persist between upgrades are copy/paste issues, random closes and apps not populating onto the start menu on initial signin

Answer (score 0):

I found it difficult to add to the win apps folder but figured out as long as the location of the apps you want to add are located in a folder named C:\Program Files\WindowsApps* it will work.  I use a folder named “WindowsApps-Import” in the programs folder, works well!

Answer (score 0):

One answer suggests adding the `-DisableDevelopmentMode` flag to the command you've ran, which works, but leaves an important point out.

Once the app installs, it won't run and crashes soon after. This is because the `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` group doesn't have access to the folder of the app. Giving `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` full control of the app folder will allow it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Move the folder inside: "C:\Users$USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages" then it works. Obv developer mode on windows needs to be ON.

for eg:
Add-AppxPackage -Register "C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Packages\WsaPackage_1.7.32815.0_x64_Release-Nightly\AppxManifest.xml"